# How to nest bash command output into an array inline?

Tags: arrays, bash, dig, variable-substitution

***Note*** - this is not a duplicate! There are other questions covering converting bash output to a bash array - ***but none of them do it inline***. The reason you need inline is because of `until`.

I'm trying to write an `until` command that parses the port from a dig command.

Here are the working commands on separate lines.

```
SERVER_DIG_RESULT=$(dig +noall +answer $SERVER_DNS_NAME SRV )
SERVER_STRING_ARRAY=($SERVER_DIG_RESULT)
SERVER_PORT=${SERVER_STRING_ARRAY[6]}
until nc -z $SERVER_DNS_NAME $SERVER_PORT
```

The problem with this is that the dns may not come online until after the first `dig` command is run, so you want the `until` command to run the `dig` over and over.

Here is my broken until command (where I try and put it on one line).

```
until nc -z $SERVER_DNS_NAME ${$(dig +noall +answer $SERVER_DNS_NAME SRV)[6]}
```

I seem to be having a problem with variable substitution. 
My question is: **How to nest bash command output into an array inline?**

Comment: Haven't tried it, but, are you sure this returns an array? `$(dig +noall +answer $SERVER_DNS_NAME SRV)`? Shouldn't be something like this? `${($(dig +noall +answer $SERVER_DNS_NAME SRV))[6]}`

Comment: The command substitution itself does not provide an array, but its white-space-separated words provide the elements for the assignment to `SERVER_STRING_ARRAY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for the `until` statement isn't limited to a single command.

```
until SERVER_STRING_ARRAY=( $(dig +noall +answer "$SERVER_DNS_NAME" SRV)
      SERVER_PORT=${SERVER_STRING_ARRAY[6]}
      nc -z "$SERVER_DNS_NAME" "$SERVER_PORT"; do
    ...
done
```